# Is there a safe way for a quick exchange of data between threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

I'm setting up an application that reads data from a load cell and, in real time, based on the data read, interrupts the thrust of a motor. It is essential to have a high frequency reading from the load cell.

I'm programming in c# and I decided to use a separate thread to acquire data from the load cell. 
My question is this: how can I use the data acquired in the thread in a thread-safe way? For example to show them in a chart.

This is the thread I call to acquire data in the queue.

```cs
Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                while (save_in_queue)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                    if (queue.Count <= 1000)
                    {
                        queue.Enqueue(Frm_main.ComPh1.LeggiAnalogica(this.Address));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        queue.Dequeue();
                        queue.Enqueue(Frm_main.ComPh1.LeggiAnalogica(this.Address));
                    }
                }
            });
            t.Name = "Queue " + this.name;
            t.Start();
```

This is method I use to associate queue filled in thread and queue in the main

```cs
        public void SetData(Queue<int> q)
        {
            this.data = q;
        }
```

This is the timer I use in the main application to set data for the series

```cs
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<int> dati = new List<int>();
            lock (data)
            {
                dati = data.ToList();
            }
            grafico.Series[serie.Name].Points.Clear();
            for (int x = 0; x < dati.Count; x++)
            {
                DataPoint pt = new DataPoint();
                pt.XValue = x;
                pt.YValues = new double[] { dati.ElementAt(x) };
                grafico.Series[serie.Name].Points.Add(pt);

            }
        }
```

This code does not work because somethimes I receive the exception
"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" on the line dati = data.ToList();

Form me it's pretty clear why I receive this exception. But how to solve it?

I would like to avoid using too many "lock" or too many synchronization variables in order not to reduce the acquisition performance, which at the moment is excellent.

Comment: Maybe through a class + public var and/or methods?

Comment: The exception occurs because you don't lock the queue in the thread. This `this.data = q;` is only a copy of the reference. The whole block `if (queue.Count <= 1000)......` must be within the lock.

Comment: If the rate of locks within the thread is too high but you still need the values, you could add them first to a local queue and add them in bulk to the shared queue. (for example per 20 values) (`queue.AddRange()`) but this doesn't work when the queue isn't a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this in your consumer thread:

```
lock (data) {
    dati = data.ToList();
}
```

You're using the queue for two different purposes; You're using it to pass data between the two threads, which is good; but you're also using it as a history buffer for previous data samples. That's bad.

What's doubly bad is, each time the timer ticks, you're locking the queue long enough to let the consumer copy maybe hundreds of data that it had previously copied on earlier ticks.

This is bad too:

```
if (queue.Count <= 1000) {
    queue.Enqueue(Frm_main.ComPh1.LeggiAnalogica(this.Address));
}
else {
    queue.Dequeue();  <== THIS IS BAD!
    queue.Enqueue(Frm_main.ComPh1.LeggiAnalogica(this.Address));
}
```

One problem with that is, you are making the producer manage the history buffer (e.g., by limiting the length of the queue), but it's the consumer who cares about the length.

Another problem is that the producer does not lock the queue.  If *any* thread needs to lock a data structure, then *every* thread needs to lock it.

---

The producer should do just one thing: It should read data from the sensor, and stuff the data into a queue.

The queue should be used for just one purpose: To communicate new data between the threads.

The producer should lock the queue just long enough to get the new data from the queue, and copy that into its own, private collection.

---

Multi-threaded programming often can be counter-intuitive. One example is; If you can decrease the amount of time that threads spend accessing a shared object by *increasing* the amount of work that each thread has to do, that often will improve the overall performance of the program. That's because locking is expensive, and because accessing memory locations that have been touched by other threads is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check Concurrent Collections namespace which provides Thread-Safe implementation of some collections

> The System.Collections.Concurrent namespace provides several
>   thread-safe collection classes that should be used in place of the
>   corresponding types in the System.Collections and
>   System.Collections.Generic namespaces whenever multiple threads are
>   accessing the collection concurrently.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent

So you can use **System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue** instead of **System.Collections.Queue** in order to provide **lock free solution** to your problem.